# Spring Boot publish repackaged submodule jar with 1.5.6

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

We've converted a maven multimodule project to gradle, and are having issues with the publishing of the spring boot jar.

Setup is like so

```
root
|- module1
|- common
|- common-test
|- module2-common
|- module2-write
|- module3-common
|- module3-write
|- module4
|- module5
|- deploy
```

`deploy` contains the repackaged jar.

When publishing (using maven-publish) the artifact is only a few kilobytes large. It's obviously not actually publishing the `deploy` jar.

#### Deploy `build.gradle.kts`

```
import org.flywaydb.gradle.task.FlywayMigrateTask
import org.springframework.boot.gradle.repackage.RepackageTask
import org.springframework.boot.gradle.run.BootRunTask

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm")
    id("org.springframework.boot") version ("1.5.6.RELEASE")
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version("1.0.6.RELEASE")
    id("org.flywaydb.flyway")
    java
}

tasks {
    withType<Jar> {
        baseName = project.name
        version = project.version as String
    }

    val implementation = configurations.getByName("implementation")
    configurations.create("includeAllJars") {
        this.extendsFrom(implementation)
    }
    withType<RepackageTask> {
        this.setCustomConfiguration("includeAllJars")
//        this.classifier = "exec"
    }
}
```

#### root `build.gradle.kts`

```
plugins {
    base
    java
    idea
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.2.51"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version ("1.2.51")
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version ("1.2.51")
    id("nebula.maven-publish") version "8.1.0"
    ...
}

allprojects {
    group = "com.company.group"

    ext {
        set("springBootVersion", "1.5.6.RELEASE")
    }
    apply {
        plugin("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm")
        plugin("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.jpa")
        plugin("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring")
    }
    dependencies {
        implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
        implementation(kotlin("reflect"))
        implementation(platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:${extra["springBootVersion"]}"))
        ...
    }
}

val sourcesJar by tasks.registering(Jar::class) {
    classifier = "sources"
    from(sourceSets["main"].allSource)
}

publishing {
    publications {
        register("maven", MavenPublication::class) {
//            from(project(":server-deploy").components["java"])
//            artifact(sourcesJar.get())
//            artifact(file("deploy/build/docker/runnable.jar"))
        }
    }
    repositories {
        ...
    }
}
```

For the publications section, I have tried specifying 
`from(components["java"])`, `artifact(file("deploy/build/libs/deploy-${project.version}.jar"))`, and the above options. All result in the published jar being only 1-3KBs large.

I have attempted moving the publications block to the deploy `build.gradle.kts`, but that results in this error

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':deploy:publishMavenPublicationToMavenLocal'.
> Failed to publish publication 'maven' to repository 'mavenLocal'
   > Invalid publication 'maven': POM file is invalid. Check any modifications you have made to the POM file.
```

[The Spring Boot docs for the gradle plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.6.RELEASE/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html#build-tool-plugins-gradle-publishing-artifacts-to-a-maven-repository) don't seem to list anything about this.

Comment: Given that you are using `platform`, you must be using Gradle 5. Spring Boot 1.x does not support Gradle 5. I'm not certain that it's causing your problem, but I would recommend using a supported version of Gradle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regards to Mr. Wilkinson's comment, he is entirely correct that Spring Boot appears to not support Gradle 5. The solution is to not use `platform()` within the one module that contains the spring boot plugin, but use `platform()` everywhere else. This is not a long term solution! This is perfect in our case because we're transitioning straight from Maven to Gradle and then immediately from Spring Boot 1 to Spring Boot 2.

#### `deploy/build.gradle.kts`

```
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version ("1.5.6.RELEASE")
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version("1.0.6.RELEASE")
    id("nebula.maven-publish")
    java
    …
}
dependencyManagement {
    imports { mavenBom("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:${extra["springBootVersion"]}") }
}
```

#### every other `build.gradle.kts` except `deploy` and `root`

```
dependencies {
    implementation(platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:${extra["springBootVersion"]}"))
    …
}
```